# How do I make a computed case statement in SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I've been researching most of the morning on how to do a computed case statement and apply a where clause to the result.

I'm attempting a SEDE query that eliminates as many lines from the select with where, then apply a computation on the remaining. The computation is expensive, as it is several like matches with wildcards.

Simple example, let me call this column Pcount:

```
CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE '%?' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+
CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE 'H%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

For "How do I SQL?", PCount should = 2 (both matched).
For "Hello my name is Alice.", PCount should = 1 (only "H%" matched).
For "Am I wrong?", PCount should = 1 (only "%?" matched).
For anything else, PCount = 0.

My first attempt used WITH:

```
WITH MyPosts (Id, Score, OwnerUserId, LastActivityDate, Tags, PCount)  
AS  
(  
Select
    Posts.Id,
    Posts.Score,
    Posts.OwnerUserId,
    Posts.LastActivityDate,
    Posts.Tags,
    (
           CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE '%?' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           +
           CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE 'H%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) as PCount
    FROM Posts
    WHERE
      Posts.Score >= ##Score##
      AND Posts.ClosedDate IS NULL

)

SELECT DISTINCT
      MyPosts.Id AS [Post Link],
      MyPosts.PCount,
      MyPosts.Score AS [Post Score],
      MyPosts.OwnerUserId AS [User Link],
      MyPosts.LastActivityDate AS [Last Activity],
      MyPosts.Tags
FROM Posts
WHERE
    PCount > 1;
```

Line 34: Invalid column name 'PCount'.
The multi-part identifier "MyPosts.Id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "MyPosts.PCount" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "MyPosts.Score" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "MyPosts.OwnerUserId" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "MyPosts.LastActivityDate" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "MyPosts.Tags" could not be bound.

But I've tried many ways, including without using WITH:

```
SELECT Pcount FROM Posts WHERE
    (
         CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE '%?' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         +
         CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE 'H%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Pcount

SELECT Pcount FROM Posts WHERE
    (SELECT (
           CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE '%?' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           +
           CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE 'H%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )) as Pcount > 1

SELECT Pcount FROM Posts WHERE
    (SELECT (
           CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE '%?' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           +
           CASE WHEN Posts.Title LIKE 'H%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) as Pcount) > 1;
```

I've [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19185043) as well as googled about adding case, but 99% of those links are not about adding. They tend to be "case blah=1 then yep1" string results.

Anyone have an example for me?

Comment: If it helps, [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) uses [tag:tsql].

Comment: Yep, that helped me a little. Eliminated MySQL results in google.

Comment: For your attempt using `WITH` - you name your CTE `MyPosts` but then use `Posts` instead in your following `FROM` clause.

Comment: Well, that worked. Sadly. I guess I can blame it on that being the 20th or more attempt today and a mistake when pivoted to there.

Comment: This is almost a full Stack Overflow question, not a meta question. Is there anything that makes it specific to SEDE, e.g., some database schema subtleties or performance considerations?

Comment: I put it here due to the performance restrictions on data.stackexchange.com. But you are right, it is mostly asking the most efficient way to make this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Bill Tür stands with Ukraine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3959259/bill-t%c3%bcr-stands-with-ukraine) already solved the majority of the problem you faced.

I went ahead and made some extra modifications. I've added an extra condition to only select Questions (PostTypeid = 1) as those only have titles. And I introduced an extra table to replace the CASE statement as I reckoned that would be easier to maintain. It is similar to query I use to [calculate the Profile Spam score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1468060/keywords-in-aboutme). Bringing all this together results in [this final version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1646995?Score=1000):

```
WITH TitleLikes as (
   Select '%?' Value
   union
   Select 'H%'
),
MyPosts (Id, Score, OwnerUserId, LastActivityDate, Tags, PCount)  
AS  
(  
Select 
    Posts.Id,
    Posts.Score,
    Posts.OwnerUserId,
    Posts.LastActivityDate,
    Posts.Tags,
    (
          Select count(*)
          From TitleLikes
          Where Posts.Title Like TitleLikes.Value
    ) as PCount
    FROM Posts
    WHERE
      Posts.Score >= ##Score:int##
      AND Posts.ClosedDate IS NULL
      And Posttypeid = 1 -- Q
)

SELECT top 1000
      MyPosts.Id AS [Post Link],
      MyPosts.PCount,
      MyPosts.Score AS [Post Score],
      MyPosts.OwnerUserId AS [User Link],
      MyPosts.LastActivityDate AS [Last Activity],
      MyPosts.Tags
FROM  MyPosts
WHERE
    PCount > 1;
```

Be careful when you use magic link columns. When the result set is huge (think > 10,000 rows) the Query Processor of SQL Server gives up and throws an error. Reducing the set with a `TOP [some number]` prevent these mishaps but in that case you might want to add an Order By that suits your use case.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).